# ubuntu 18 - "sudo apt install tor" fails with "Depends: libevent-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable) but it is not installable"

Tags: apt, tor

i am trying to install tor as explained at this link:

[Install Tor on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/install-tor-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

but it fails as shown below:

```
$ sudo apt install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 tor : Depends: libevent-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable) but it is not installable
       Recommends: tor-geoipdb but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: torsocks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what am i doing wrong?

**edit**: `snap install tor` did the trick.  thanks guiverc.

**edit #2**: additional info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ apt-cache policy tor
tor:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.5.8-1~d90.stretch+1
  Version table:
     0.3.5.8-1~d90.stretch+1 500
        500 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch/main amd64 Packages
     0.3.2.10-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

prior to fixing my problem with `snap install tor`, i had already installed tor browser.  by running the command `torbrowser-launcher` i could get the tor process to start, but i couldn't figure out how to run the tor process/demon without starting the tor browser.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18, however there is Ubuntu Core 18 (based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS intended for IoT appliances). I don't see the package either outside of available for xenial [16.04] (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor) however maybe you could try the Ubuntu instructions and snap package? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor

Comment: It is a bit strange, the `tor` package exists in [all Ubuntu versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=tor).  What is the output of `apt-cache policy tor` on your system? What is your exact Ubuntu version?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, i edited my OP with the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in a comment by guiverc, `snap install tor` did the trick.

"you can accept your own answer in 2 days"... :|

Comment: not works for me

Answer (score 0):

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/01/install-tor-tor-browser-ubuntu-20-10-20-04/

This worked for me. Remove what you added with your previous try in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and re-try with this version of repository adding and installing.